# TCP/IP Window Socket//server (C++) and Client(java) ..not Working

Tags: tcp

iam doing some simulation and i have writting an application using java who communicate with a server writting in c\c++.
The problem it is not working and i want to know if it's possible?

I don't want to use Corba or something like that..

Answer (score 1):

We'll need a lot more information to diagnose the actual problem, but yes, a java program can definitely communicate with a C/C++ server over TCP/IP.

Answer (score 0):

It's very possible, even (especially?) using pure tcp sockets. A socket is a socket in any language...  The data you send across it may need some interpreting, however.